# How to know that anime series which episodes are filler?

Tags: anime-production

I have found a site [Anime Filler List](https://theanimefiller.com/) so I want to know that is this real ?

Comment: If you're looking to us to vet its authenticity, that's a tall ask.  There have been cases in which filler has bled into canon.

Comment: Are you asking for a specific series? If so, which series? This question might be closed because it is too broad.

Comment: You can just google search "X anime filler list" and the first link will most likely be the right one.

Comment: Also most fillers don't have much to do with the Anime and some are pretty boring so they are easy to spot after a few minutes. Though some fillers are good, like the ones in Naruto (not Naruto Shippuden).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of One Piece, if you click [here](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Story_Arcs) you will access the anime's wiki page, which clearly separates the arcs and sagas as well as shows which episodes are fillers.

**If you type into google "[anime name] wiki story arcs" you should find the arcs, sagas and fillers listed on the page, showing you which episode belongs to which**, especially for the more popular and lengthy anime.

As for when to know episodes are filler, you'll know when the episodes go off track with the main goal of the main characters. Fillers can still be fun to watch and if you enjoy the anime, I don't recommend skipping.

One last thing regarding the list you provided. It's probably a good idea to compare these episodes against wiki as well as some other sources to check its authenticity.

Hope this helps!